# How to change the document content's width?

Tags: react-styleguidist

The default `max-width` of 'main' element is `1000px`, I want to make it wider. I tried the [customize style instruction](https://react-styleguidist.js.org/docs/cookbook.html#how-to-change-styles-of-a-style-guide) but cannot locate the 'main' element or the 'rsg--content-xx' class by below config in 'styleguide.config.js'

```
styles: {
  StyleGuide: {
    'rsg--content': {
      maxWidth: 1300,
      width: 1300
    },
    '@global main': {
      maxWidth: 1300,
      width: 1300
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be very appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs it should be something like this:

```
styles: {
  StyleGuide: {
    content: {
      maxWidth: 1300
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works! It's better to put the relate html markup beside the example of the `styles` in the documentation to help people understand how it works.

Comment: Feel free to send a pull request — docs are never perfect ;-)

Comment: This answer no longer works. See my explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53675663/4642023

Answer (score 5):

The `styles` function in the [StyleGuideRenderer](https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist/blob/ec3a477cc4a4baf35cfda571de7bde1826edf61c/src/client/rsg-components/StyleGuide/StyleGuideRenderer.js#L10) component takes the theme as the argument. `maxWidth` is set in the [theme](https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist/blob/ec3a477cc4a4baf35cfda571de7bde1826edf61c/src/client/styles/theme.js#L75). You can override theme properties in styleguide.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    maxWidth: 1300
  }
}
```